# How to update Query automatically by checking today condition?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I want to update query automatically, When the today is greater than today.

**table camp_details**

```
camp_details
---------------
Camp_name,
Description,
fromdate,
todate, 
status
```

**My Query**

```
$this->db->where('todate' > NOW());
$up_reg = $this->db->update('camp',array('status' => 0));
```

when `todate` greater than today the status will automatically be updated to 0.

Comment: Show us some of your code

Comment: I just added details with from date and to date with status = 1, when todate > now() means the staus wants t0 be update like this status = 0

Comment: tell us what you've tried and how isn't it working. Expected output , table structure , and other details. without them we're pretty useless unless you can share your workstation with someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is with the mysql NOW() which returns a value like this

> 2014-11-11 12:45:34

using CURDATE() results in a value like this

> 2014-11-11

You might want to use CURDATE() to get from the database.
Refer to this link for sql now(). [mysql NOW()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much. Got it.

Comment: @shruthi Plese mark this as the answer if it helped you so that others may find it helpfull